# Do Americans still need extra health care / medical insurance after reform to health care? [U.S.]

Tags: united-states, healthcare, insurance, budget

Does the passage of the recent bill in the US change the way Americans budget for health care?  If so who benefits?

Comment: My wife is an insurance broker, she is still waiting for the carriers to tell her the new rules.  The information is from biased sources so far, so I personally can't make heads or tails of it.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is too early to tell. They changed so many variables in an incredibly complex system, and a lot of it will depend on how the requirements in the legislation look once the bureaucrats and insurance companies get a chance to interpret them and implement them as policy.

My gut feeling is that for most people, you should plan on some pretty price increases for insurance in the next few years as insurance companies try cover the costs of removing lifetime caps and insuring people with pre-existing conditions.

That said, the personal finance issue that you really should be planning for is your portfolio not your insurance costs. The bill includes almost a 4% increase in capital gains taxes.

Comment: But now that everybody is required to have insurance, there are more people in the pool and that should lower the costs.  It is so complex.

Comment: No kidding. That bill is supposedly 2,000 pages long and I keep hearing about new things that are in it. I suppose we won't know for sure until this grand experiment has run its course for a while.